# Custom scrollbar for panel does not scroll smoothly

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

customBtn1 is the custom scrollbar. The below code sample works, but the scrolling action is jittery and stuttery. It does not scroll smoothly. Any idea why this could be happening and how to fix it?

```
    int PreviousBarLoc;
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PreviousBarLoc= customBtn1.Location.Y;
    }

    //move the scrollbar up and down when the user drags it
    private void customBtn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        { MouseDownLocation = e.Location; }
    }
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    private void customBtn1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            customBtn1.Top = e.Y + customBtn1.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }
    }
    
    //scroll the panel
    private void customBtn1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int locDifference = customBtn1.Location.Y - PreviousBarLoc;
        if (steamSrvListPnl.VerticalScroll.Value + locDifference <= 255 && steamSrvListPnl.VerticalScroll.Value + locDifference >= 0)
        {
            steamSrvListPnl.VerticalScroll.Value += locDifference;
        }
        PreviousBarLoc= customBtn1.Location.Y;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your deltas are not quite right. The way it is currently written, if you drag the mouse down and then start dragging back up, it will not scroll back up because your current e.Y is still below the original MouseDownLocation.Y. I'm not entirely sure of your setup, but below is an example of how to get smooth scrolling to work when the left mouse button is pressed and dragged on a button:

```
    private int _prevY = 0;
    private bool _mouseDown = false;
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _mouseDown = true;
            _prevY = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Math.Max(panel1.VerticalScroll.Minimum, Math.Min(panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum, panel1.VerticalScroll.Value + e.Y - _prevY));
            _prevY = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            _mouseDown = false;
            _prevY = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this piece of code and the scrolling is still stuttery and weird

Comment: Interesting, I created a new winforms .net framework app and added this code and it seems to be smooth for me. I would recommend creating a test application with just this code to verify that there's not something else going on.

Comment: I created a new application and tested the code. Its still not working properly. By the way that stuttery effect mostly happens when i move the bar slowly

Comment: You'll have to share more of your control setup. Specific properties can cause all kinds of ugly things in WinForms.